# How to pass --debug to build_ext when invoking setup.py install?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, python-extensions

When I execute a command `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` it would execute `build_ext` command as one of the steps. How can I pass `--debug` option to it as if it was invoked as `python setup.py build_ext --debug`?

UPDATE
Here is a `setup.py` very similar to mine:
https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/11a644072b12ad78352b6e6649db9dfe7f406676/setup.py#L43

I'd like to invoke `python setup.py install` but turn `debug` property in `build_ext` class instance to 1.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? Error message? Could you please show that?

Comment: @Xilpex, here is an example code: https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/11a644072b12ad78352b6e6649db9dfe7f406676/setup.py#L43

Comment: So you want to always pass the option to *build\_ext*. Do you want to pass it just to any sub command?  What doesn't work for the file given as an example?

Comment: @CristiFati, of course I don't want to always pass it. Option should be optional. The use case is that sometimes I want to install a release build and sometimes - a development build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**A.** If I am not mistaken, one could achieve that by adding the following to a `setup.cfg` file alongside the `setup.py` file:

```
[build_ext]
debug = 1
```

**B.1.** For more flexibility, I believe it should be possible to be explicit on the command line:

```
$ path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py build_ext --debug install
```

**B.2.** Also if I understood right it should be possible to define so-called aliases

```
# setup.cfg
[aliases]
release_install = build_ext install
debug_install = build_ext --debug install
```

```
$ path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py release_install
$ path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py debug_install
```

**References**

- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#alias-define-shortcuts-for-commonly-used-commands

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below to do it

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.install import install
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext

class InstallLocalPackage(install):
    def run(self):
        build_ext_command = self.distribution.get_command_obj("build_ext")
        build_ext_command.debug = 1
        build_ext.run(build_ext_command)
        install.run(self)

setup(
    name='psetup',
    version='1.0.1',
    packages=[''],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='tarunlalwani',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallLocalPackage
    }
)
```